# Plotting a 3D array second by second without converting it to 2D with np.concatenate, np.append or indexing

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, multidimensional-array

```
x = np.array[[[8, 7, 1, 0, 3],
              [2, 8, 5, 5, 2],
              [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]],

             [[8, 4, 1, 0, 0],
              [6, 8, 5, 5, 2],
              [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]],

             [[2, 4, 0, 2, 3],
              [2, 5, 5, 3, 2],
              [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]],

             [[4, 7, 2, 8, 0],
              [1, 3, 6, 5, 2],
              [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]]
```

I have a `NumPy` array called `x` and I want to plot it. Each 5 columns of data here represents 1 second. So my array is 5*4=20 seconds of data. I want this array, which I will draw with the `plt.imshow` command, to increase by appending it next to it every second. In other words, only

```
[8, 7, 1, 0, 3],
[2, 8, 5, 5, 2],
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

will be drawn in the first second, then

```
[[8, 7, 1, 0, 3, 8, 4, 1, 0, 0],
 [2, 8, 5, 5, 2, 6, 8, 5, 5, 2],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

will be drawn in the second second, and so on for up to 4 seconds.

But before that we need to see our array increment every second.
You can reach the image I want to get below.
[image]

But there is a very important problem here. My real-life array is much larger. Therefore, when I want to convert the 3D array I have into 2D with `np.concatenate`, `np.append` or `indexing`, my computer crashes because array is too big. Is there any way I can do this with the `matplotlib` library without converting it to 2D? I think it can be done with a for loop, but the problem here is, in the examples I've seen on the internet, they completely refresh the image, not append it next to the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED ANSWER:**

The following code took less than 5 minutes of running time on my laptop with 8GB of RAM, and with a data array of shape (475,5400,200).

```
d1,d2,d3 = 475,5400,200 # dimensions of the data

# Create some data
values = np.zeros((d1,d2,d3))
values[:] = 1+np.cos(np.arange(d2)/200)[:,None]
values[:] *= 1+np.sin(np.arange(d1*d3)/1000).reshape(d1,d3)[:,None,:]

# Produce plots
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,2))
plt.xlim((0,d1*d3))
yaxis = range(d2,-1,-1)
vmin = values.min()
vmax = values.max()

# plot a background of zeros
plt.pcolormesh([0,d1*d3],[d2,0],[[0]], vmin=vmin,vmax=vmax)
plt.savefig('test-000.png')
plt.clf() # clear figure

# plot the data
for i,v in enumerate(values):
    print(i)
    plt.xlim((0,d1*d3)); plt.xticks([], ""); plt.yticks([], "")
    xaxis = range(i*d3,(i+1)*d3+1)
    plt.pcolormesh(xaxis,yaxis,v, vmin=vmin,vmax=vmax)
    plt.savefig('test-{:03d}.png'.format(i+1), transparent=True)
    plt.clf() # clear figure
plt.close()
```

The above code produces 476 frames that need to be overlayed to form an animated gif. I used ImageMagick for that:

```
convert -delay 2 -layers 'optimize' -dispose none test-*.png test.gif
```

This is the resulting animation:

[image: pcolormesh animation]

I hope this method works on your computer too!

...

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:** (does not work for OP, as his computer runs out of RAM)

I don't know how to do it with `imshow` but here is how I did it with `pcolormesh`:

```py
d1,d2,d3 = x.shape # dimensions of x
vmin = x.min()
vmax = x.max()

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,2))
plt.xlim((0,d1*d3))
yaxis = range(d2,-1,-1)

# plot a background of zeros
xaxis = range(0,d1*d3+1)
plt.pcolormesh(xaxis,yaxis,np.zeros((d2,d1*d3)), vmin=vmin,vmax=vmax)
plt.savefig('test-0.png')

# plot your data 5 seconds at a time
for i,xi in enumerate(x):
    xaxis = range(i*d3,(i+1)*d3+1)
    plt.pcolormesh(xaxis,yaxis,xi, vmin=vmin,vmax=vmax)
    plt.savefig('test-{}.png'.format(i+1))
plt.close()
```

This piece of code saves a frame for every 5 seconds in png format. In order to produce the animated gif below, I used ImageMagick: `convert -delay 50 test*.png test.gif`

[image: animated gif]

I am sure there are more efficient ways to produce the animation instead of saving every frame and then making a gif out of the frames.
However, I do not have a lot of experience with matplotlib and animated plots so maybe someone else can recommend a better way to produce the animated gif?

Comment: Thank you, I'm gonna try this.

Comment: Sorry but it didn't work. The array I'm actually working with is too big and that's probably why it's not working. I think this method consumes a lot of RAM.

Comment: @mehmet_kacmaz_03 How big is your array? (and how much RAM do you have). Maybe you'll get it to work if you reduce the image quality, and depending on the size of the image, that loss in quality might not even be visible to the eye. Try `fig = plt.figure(dpi=10)`, but maybe even a smaller `dpi` might be necessary, so try smaller values for `dpi` too.

Comment: Thank you, I will try right away. By the way the dimensions of the array are (475,5400,200) and my RAM is 12 Gb.

Comment: @mehmet_kacmaz_03 . I updated my answer with a method that takes up very little RAM and is much faster than my original answer. I hope this will work on your computer too.